# Optimize eulerproject solution 5 - smallest multiple

Tags: python, optimization

How can I optimize my code? It took my about 3minutes to finally get my answer.

This is m code:

```
def myfunc():
    smallest = 0;
    while True:
        smallest +=1
        for x in range(1, 21):
            if smallest % x != 0:
                break
            else:
                if x == 20:
                    print(smallest)
                    return
myfunc()
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate the *least common multiple* of all elements ranging from 1 to (and including) 20.

The least common multiple (lcm) of three (or more numbers) `lmc(a,b,c) == lmc(lmc(a,b),c)`.

Now in order to calculate the least common multiple we can calculate the *greatest common divisor* (gcd) using the Euclidean algorithm:

```
def gcd(x,y):
    while y != 0:
        x, y = y, x % y
    return x
```

So now we can define `lcm` in terms of `gcd`:

```
def lcm(x,y):
    return x*y//gcd(x,y)
```

And then let it work for a list:

```
def lcm_list(x,*args):
    for y in args:
        x = lcm(x,y)
    return x
```

So now we can calculate it like:

```
lcm_list(*range(1,21))
```

This generates:

```
>>> lcm_list(*range(1,21))
232792560
```

and it is divisible by every number from 1 to 20:

```
>>> [232792560%i for i in range(1,21)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved analytically. No programming needed.

The logic goes as follows: If `n` divides a number `k`, then it also divides `k * m`. Hence the number we're looking for is the product of all numbers `n` which can *not* be written as a product of any smaller numbers in the set.

None of these numbers can be a non-prime power composite number, since otherwise it is the product of smaller numbers already in the set, but on the other hand it has to contain all prime-powers smaller than 20, since these are not the product of any smaller numbers in the set. Since we know the prime numbers (by heart, or consult some list/write a function) we now have a solution.

Hence my code would be

```
>>> (2 ** 4) * (3 ** 2) * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
232792560
```

Comment: Your reasoning is off. For example, 2^4 can be written as 2 * 2^3.

Comment: Well, then both 2 and 2^3 has to be in the list, otherwise you count something twice. So your solution would give `2 *
 (2 ** 3) * (3 ** 2) * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19`, which gives the same result.

Comment: With that reasoning, you'd have to include both 3 and 3^2. While multiplying all maximal prime powers up to 20 does give the right result, the logic you've used to reach that multiplication has numerous holes in it.

Comment: Of course it has holes, this is a programming forum, not the annals of mathematics. Anyone looking to formalize this would easily fill in the blanks if necessary. The main ideas are there and I honestly doubt going into the dirty details would help anyone reading this question.